# Angular block scroll content

Tags: javascript, css, angular, webpack-2

I build angular using webpack 2 and my project structure as below:
[image]

I ran success in locally, and than I upload all file inside dist folder to my tomcat server.

[image]

I tried to see my website and my problems come.

[image]

I cannot scroll down my website. seems like something block my scroll. when i ran locally is no problem.

anyone please help to resolve my problem.
Thanks :)

Comment: Are you getting console errors?

Comment: Cant say much about it as there is no code. If you know once try `overflow` property.

Comment: Maybe an issue with the build? Clear your dist folder and do another ng build --prod --aot

Maybe even a cache issue?

Comment: @ZackSunderland, first when open my website..directly go to login (but in web console i found Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) for login)..then after login go to main page (actualy the main page i put in loadchildren inside angular-router). in the main page i also found in the console 404 for main url, but i still can see my main page

Comment: Hi @SaiUnique ..i dont know also which code need to show because i dont where the problem comes from :), any suggest which code need to show?.

Comment: Hi @Surreal, i already try rebuild and delete dist folder, but still not working. Thanks (actually i use npm start and my angular automatic rebuild)